# How to set up nginx in ubuntu with virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have installed ubuntu on virtual box. Then, I installed nginx, php, php-fpm, and mysql. When I try to set configurations for nginx, it keeps giving me the error below. What could I solve this problem?

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Error

```
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup nginx[27774]: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:58
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup nginx[27774]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 21 14:58:35 develop-truckup systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is sites-available/default/www.conf

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root {dir where my index.php is (e.g. /home/example }

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}
```

Here is /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
; the variable $pool can be used in any directive and will be replaced by the
; pool name ('www' here)
[www]

; Per pool prefix
; It only applies on the following directives:
; - 'access.log'
; - 'slowlog'
; - 'listen' (unixsocket)
; - 'chroot'
; - 'chdir'
; - 'php_values'
; - 'php_admin_values'
; When not set, the global prefix (or /usr) applies instead.
; Note: This directive can also be relative to the global prefix.
; Default Value: none
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock

; Set listen(2) backlog.
; Default Value: 511 (-1 on FreeBSD and OpenBSD)
;listen.backlog = 511

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0660
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
;listen.mode = 0660
; When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
; these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
; When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored
;listen.acl_users =
;listen.acl_groups =
```

Here is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: The error are pretty self-explanatory:
`"fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:58`
Check line 58 in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file. It's included with other configs.

Comment: @NStorm `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is symlinked with `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. I have tried to remove `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, then it did not give the error on start, however, nginx was not found `using netstat -tulpn`

Comment: @smchae, you shouldn't remove the file, rather comment out the line 58 and see if the error is gone.

Comment: @Diamant If I comment out the line 58 in `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` then line 58 in `etc/nginx/sites-available/default` would be commented out as well. And it gives me http error 500

Comment: @smchae, does it mean that nginx starts then? Anyway, it seems you are completely new to nginx or linux at all (correct me if I am wrong). If it is so, then take some time and read some documentaion. Try to understand what you are doing: i.e. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04. You can also use `nginx -t` to check configuration, also should look at syslog, and nginx log. Something more advanced: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @Diamant Yes. It worked. Somehow I was very confused with what I was doing. Thank you!

Comment: @smchae, good to hear that. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is pretty clear:

```
nginx[27774]: nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:58
```

May be you can comment out the line 58 and restart nginx to see if the error is gone. 
You can also use `nginx -t` to check configuration, also should look at syslog, and nginx log.

Please take some time and read some documentaion which will help you to understand what you are doing: i.e. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Or something more advanced: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04